# Adding separators for date which are without separators using vb.net

Tags: datetime, vb.net-2010

I have a date in the format '13092017' to which i have to add separator '-'and display in the text box using vb.net.

```
    Private Sub SettlementDetailUpload_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        Dim s1 As String = "13092017"


    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want the output : `13-09-2017`?

Comment: yes with any separators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that :

```
Private Sub SettlementDetailUpload_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim s1 As String = "13092017"
        Dim DayStr, MonthStr, YearStr, FinalDate As String

        DayStr = s1.Remove(2)
        MonthStr = s1.Substring(2, 2) 'The first '2' is where to start cutting and the 2nd '2' is how much you need to cutm which is 2 in this case.
        YearStr = s1.Substring(4)

        FinalDate = DayStr & "-" & MonthStr & "-" & YearStr
        Msgbox(FinalDate)
    Catch : End Try
End Sub
```

Hope it will be useful :)